# Linking to a Facebook Page with iOS6

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

So I am trying to link to a Facebook page on iOS6 from my app using

```
NSString* urlString = @"https://www.facebook.com/vioside";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

This opens up the Facebook app successfully but it doesn't go on my page. Anyone has an idea on how to link properly on iOS6?

Comment: **Facebook app successfully** what do you mean by this ? and where it is going .... it would open your page in safari ... what're you getting ?

Comment: It is opening the Facebook native app. Probably since iOS6 has Facebook integration, a facebook link would open the Facebook native app instead of the web app in safari. It opens the facebook native app but remains on my news feed without going to the page

Comment: Nope at my end it is opening your page in safari ... with IOS 6.

Comment: So you made an app with the above code and it's opening safari? Do you have the native app installed with facebook integration setup in settings? :)

Comment: Actually, it did open is safari when I did, example, http://facebook.com/vioside. with the www in there, it's opening the app without taking me to the page... weired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this myself by removing the 'www' from the url. It's funny but with the 'www' is only opens the Facebook app, after removing it, safari is opened instead and views the proper page. Maybe it's an iOS6 bug but this worked for me

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you may not use the short name.  It has to be the 'id' for it to work currently.

[iOS6 and facbook URLs not opening correctly in facebook app](http://barelyrelevant.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/ios6-and-facbook-urls-not-opening-correctly-in-facebook-app/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace "www.facebook.com" with "m.facebook.com":

```
NSString* urlString = @"https://m.facebook.com/vioside";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

Answer (score -1):

it's working fine i tested it as like:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* urlString = @"https://www.facebook.com/vioside";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
}
```